# Why won't window.location load a new page?

Tags: javascript, html, url, redirect, window.location

This bit of code used to work, and now it doesn't:

```
var url = myurl +'?id=' + id + '&phase=' + phase;
window.location = url;
```

Using the IE dev toolbar I've verified that url has a valid url, and window.location returns the new url...the only problem is the page does not reload.

Does anyone know of any reasons for window.location to now actually load a new document when it is assigned to?

Comment: Yeah, try printing out the URL manually and see what it actually contains.

Comment: For my problem, it is another url in my system.

Comment: Doesn't work with 'www.google.com' either

Comment: try document.location and you will see results

Comment: Are you sure that the code is actually executing? Have it pop up an alert just before then or something, and make sure there are no errors too

Comment: FYI document.location is sometimes readonly and isn't necessarily cross-browser since it's not part of the DOM spec. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/document.location

Comment: What version of IE are you running? This should work..

Comment: I'm running IE8, and it's a corporate app, so that's all I need to worry about. The code is definitely executing, I stepped through it with the VS Debugger.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks to [@Senad Meskin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/244929/senad-meskin).

```
document.location = url;
```

worked for me. Any reason why window would stop working?

Comment: No, but document.location is not cross-browser either, since originally it was read-only. You probably won't hit any issues, but you may want to research more on why it isn't running.

Answer (score 13):

Use `window.location.href = url;` instead.

Comment: No javascript errors. This was working for me before, and I'm not sure what changed to cause it to stop.

Comment: "This was working for me before, and I'm not sure what changed..." - figure out what changed.  It was NOT this code, I'm guessing.

Answer (score 4):

Is your JavaScript running the onclick event from an <input> type="**button**" or type="**submit**"?

If your button is type="submit" it won't work unless you stop the submission from executing.

I know this is kind of obvious but I didn't see this in the other comments so I might just add to this thread.

Answer (score 1):

So i just got this same error today, I for some reason couldn't get my page to redirect to google (just for testing purposes). Copied the code directly from another site and it worked, so i tried google.com again - low and behold it didn't work...

I should also mention that i'm trying to redirect a page in an iframe, not the entire webpage.

So I fired up my trusty Max's HTML Beauty++ 2004 and opened my page in that, sure enough it gave me my error:

> This content cannot be displayed in a frame
>
> ```
>  To help protect the security of information you enter into this  
>  website, the publisher of this content does not allow it to be
>  displayed in a frame.
> ```

The code i Used to get that:

```
window.location = "http://www.google.com";
```

It looks like browsers don't display this error, instead they just don't redirect you... Kind of confusing :/

Answer (score 0):

I was using jquery, and a similar problem cropped up and I had to resolve it by adding the `data-ajax=false` attribute to the `<a href="...` link.