# Is this the correct way to redirect?

Tags: javascript, redirect

In reponse to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6764243/why-wont-window-location-load-a-new-page/6764352#6764352) I wrote this function (well, I made it a bit more elaborate then in that answer):

```
function redirectto(url) {
    window.location.href = url; // first try it the easy way

    // we're going to do it the hard way - create a temporary form and submit it
    var tmpform = document.createElement("form");
    tmpform.method = "GET";

    // add data, use hidden fields for querystrings
    if (url.indexOf("?") == -1) {
        tmpform.action = url;
    } else {
        var urlparts = url.split("?", 2);
        tmpform.action = urlparts[0];

        var queryparts = urlparts[1].replace(/\+/g, " ").split(/[&;]/g);
        for (var i = 0; i < queryparts.length; i++) {
            var pair = queryparts[i].split("=");
            var key = pair[0];
            var value = pair.length > 1 ? pair[1] : "";

            var field;
            try { // sigh IE, can't you do ANYTHING right?
                field = document.createElement("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"" + key + "\" value=\"" + value + "\">");
            } catch(err) {
                field = document.createElement("input");
                field.type = "hidden";
                field.name = key;
                field.value = value;
            }
            tmpform.appendChild(field);
        }
    }

    // add to page and submit
    document.body.appendChild(tmpform);
    tmpform.submit();
}
```

The answer I wrote got 3 downvotes, so my question is: is this the correct way to do this or is simply `window.location.href = url` enough?

Comment: Why do you think that `window.location.href = url;` would fail in IE?

Comment: Why submit a form rather then inject a `<a>` into the page and click that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`window.location.href = url` is *a* valid way of redirecting the browser. Typically I discourage browser redirection unless absolutely necessary. There tend to be few *good* reasons to redirect via JS.

Comment: Sure, valid by the standard, but my question is if it will always work (glares at IE).

Comment: @nightcracker As I commented above: Why do you think that `window.location.href = url;` would fail in IE?

Comment: The question linked in the OP.

Comment: @nightcracker, if you have any reason to believe it wont work in a browser, run this in the location bar: `javascript:window.location.href='http://www.google.com/';`.

Answer (score 0):

its is better to use the built in method as it is more efficient and more widely supported by most of the browsers running javascript and also requires less memory that loading a whole new function and running that.

And window.location.href = url is a valid way of redirecting the browser as zzzzBov said

Answer (score 0):

I think `window.location.href = url` is enough.